# How to represent $x = -6$ in terms of $y$?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have the equation $x = 0$ which needs to only be graphed when the y values are between 0 and 3. This can be represented as the following equation.
$$x=0y,\quad \{0<y<3\}$$
How can I do the same thing with the equation $x=-6$ where it is only graphed when the y values are between 0 and 3?

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you give more context?

Comment: By saying $x = -6$.

Comment: You *could* write $\,x = 0 \cdot y -6\,$ though I don't know why you'd want to do that.

Comment: @Cornman see my updated question.

Comment: draw the graph x = -6 for all y and then erase the y's that you don't want

Comment: Actually I like dxiv's comment.  If $y = mx +b$ or $x =ny + c$ then shifting it to six units to the left is $y = m(x+6) + b$  or $x = ny + c -6$.  So if $x = 0*y$ (although we have utterly no idea why one would want to write that) then we could write $x = 0*y - 6$.

Comment: @dxiv Your answer was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Riz-waan I don't see how writing it that way helps with what appears to be the actual question: `needs to only be graphed when the y values are between 0 and 3`. $x=-6$ is a vertical line, and $0 \lt y \lt 3$ is the horizontal stripe between the lines $y=0$ and $y=3$. When you intersect the two, you get the graph as a vertical segment.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning here [parametric equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation).  One could express your segment as $x(t)=-6,~y(t)=t$ for $t$ in the range $0<t<3$., or however you prefer to notate it.